# Display data from db to JSP page with update and delete links corresponding each row?

Tags: jsp

This question has been asked many a times. Just **extending** it. I want to  display database table data onto a JSP page table and 2 links follow each row. First is, Update. Second, Delete. Assume that each row has an **id** associated with it **coming from database itself**, how can I create this links and pass **id** so that when I press Delete, corresponding row is deleted. Also, how do I update values with **id**?

```
<TABLE BORDER="1">
        <TR>
            <TH>ID</TH>
            <TH>Name</TH>
            <TH>Address</TH>
            <TH>Update</TH>
            <TH>Delete</TH>
        </TR>
        <% while(resultset.next()){ %>

        <TR>
            <TD> <%= resultset.getString(1) %></td>
            <TD> <%= resultset.getString(2) %></TD>
            <TD> <%= resultset.getString(3) %></TD>
            <TD> <a href="#">Update</a> </td>
            <TD> <a href="#">Delete</a> </TD>
        </TR>
        <% } %>
    </TABLE>
```

Comment: @Tiny How will I extract the url parameter from the url jsp I am sending this id to?

Comment: Using `request.getParameter("id");` where `id` refers to the URL query-string parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to created tow different ulr of one common url with different parameters for updation,deletion. Find below code to delete or update particular record.

Assume delete JSP is `del.jsp` and update JSP is `update.jsp`

```
<TABLE BORDER="1">
        <TR>
            <TH>ID</TH>
            <TH>Name</TH>
            <TH>Address</TH>
            <TH>Update</TH>
            <TH>Delete</TH>
        </TR>
        <% while(resultset.next()){ %>

        <TR>
            <TD> <%= resultset.getString(1) %></td>
            <TD> <%= resultset.getString(2) %></TD>
            <TD> <%= resultset.getString(3) %></TD>
            <TD> <a href="update.jsp?id=<%=resultset.getString(1) %>">Update</a> </td>
            <TD> <a href="del.jsp?id=<%=resultset.getString(1) %>">Delete</a> </TD>
        </TR>
        <% } %>
    </TABLE>
```

Get id value in get form on `del.jsp` and `update.jsp` and update OR delete the values corresponding to id.

Comment: Can I handle both the requests, update and delete, in the same jsp in some way? It really looks like an overhead to create 2 jsp files just to modify or delete a row in a table. I mean what when I will be creating a big app with lots of tables and lots of operations!

Comment: @Shubham Yes, you can do same in one jsp file simplye add one parameter name `action` with jsp file and pass action like update/delete with that and get this action in jsp and perform update/delete query according to action parameter values. e.g. `updateDelete.jsp?id=xyz&action=delete`  or `updateDelete.jsp?id=xyz&action=update` perform sql query according to action value. Hope you have got it. :)